# How to get the size of the output of a Direct2D Effect?

Tags: windows, direct2d

I need to know the size of the output of a [Direct2D Effect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh973240.aspx). Say, for example, to render the effect to a bitmap for later use. For example, of the built-in Gaussian blur effect.

[`ID2D1Effect`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh404566.aspx) does not have a `GetSize()` member. It does have `GetOutput()`, but the resulting [`ID2D1Image`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh446803.aspx) does not have a `GetSize()` member either. Or anything even remotely related.

An effect *could* have an unlimited output, adapted to the rendertarget, but I expect not. When you write [custom effects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/jj710194.aspx), the internal transform graph has, somewhere, functions like `MapInputRectsToOutputRect()`. Is it accessible from the app for built-in effects?

Did I miss anything? Is it at all possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`ID2D1DeviceContext::GetImageLocalBounds`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh404515(v=vs.85).aspx) method probably is what you are looking for.